# Get authentication scheme from request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have set up an API in ASPNET with .NET 6, where I am registering two schemes in my autentication service.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("MyDefaultScheme")
  .AddJwtBearer("MyDefaultScheme", options => { ... })
  .AddJwtBearer("SomeSecondaryScheme", options => { ... });
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
```

These are two different authorities that both issues valid JWT tokens.

In my API controllers, I have set up different controllers which responds to these two schemes, using the "AuthenticationSchemes" property in the `[Authorize]` attribute. But I also have a controller that accepts tokens from both schemes.

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "MyDefaultScheme,SomeSecondaryScheme")]
public class SomeApiController : ControllerBase
{
  ...
}
```

This works good, but my question is:

**Is there a way to find which auth scheme the token comes from, in the request context or a helper?**

The reason for this is that the data I'm looking for may exist under different scope names depending on whether the token is issued by "MyDefaultScheme" or "SomeSecondaryScheme". Like username that may exist in the "sub" claim in one scheme and "preferred_username" in the other. Or that roles are named differently, but handled the same.

In that case, it would be nice to know which scheme it came from and do a switch based on that. I know I can get the "iss" claim value and then parse IAuthenticationHandlerProvider from GetRequiredService, but I'm looking for a simpler solution, if any.

Thanks!

Comment: I think, at least, if we can get the token from request header in Controller, we can decode the jwt token then we may find some useful information in the claims.

Comment: Yeah, what I do now is to get the "iss" claim and look for that issuer within the options of my schemes in AddJwtBearer. But I just wonder if there was a better way of doing this :) Like if there is something to get directly from the HttpContext or something.

Comment: not so sure about if there was a better way... never did that before. sorry for it...

Answer (score 0):

There's a request feature that lets you find out which authentication scheme authenticated the user.

`this.HttpContext.Features.Get<IAuthenticateResultFeature>().AuthenticateResult?.Ticket?.AuthenticationScheme`

Note, lots of null coalescing there!

Comment: I've tried this too, but in the context of the question I got something like "MyDefaultScheme;SomeSecondaryScheme" which failed in the next stages... I'm thinking of Brute-forcing it by String.Split-ting them and testing them one by one in suppressed try-catches but I'm hoping there's a better way...

Answer (score -1):

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization("MyDefaultScheme");
```

Comment: Thanks. But what I need is to find out is which issuer the token that is used inside the methods in my controller. I have User.Identity and User.Claims, but it would be nice to know if the used token is let's say a Microsoft Graph token or a Firebase token (if those are the ones I support in my API).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: i do this `claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, Role)` and add in Program.cs `builder.Services.AddAuthorization(config =>{config.AddPolicy("UserPolicy", policyBuilder =>{ policyBuilder.RequireRole(ClaimTypes.Role);});});`

Comment: If you want to use a different one, you just change it. `ClaimTypes` then add in Program.cs

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure you quite get what I'm asking for here...